# CMake with MSVC Ninja gives compiler & test program error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, c++17, ninja

I have the following C++ build setup (using MSVC 2019 + Ninja):

**build.bat**

```bsh
@echo off
mkdir build_folder
cd build_folder
call "C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" ..
cd ..
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```bsh
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
project(TestScript CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} Script.cpp)
```

**Script.cpp**

```cpp
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

But when running `build.bat` I get this output:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.21.27702.2
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:53 (message):
  The C++ compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.21.27702/bin/HostX64/x64/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Coding/cmake_msvc_test/build_folder/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_6ecce
    [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmTC_6ecce.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
    [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmTC_6ecce.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_6ecce.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_6ecce.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2019\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1421~1.277\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_6ecce.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj  /out:cmTC_6ecce.exe /implib:cmTC_6ecce.lib /pdb:cmTC_6ecce.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /foCMakeFiles\cmTC_6ecce.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_6ecce.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I assume my **cmake ninja** call in `build.bat` is not quite correct (in terms of includes & compiler paths, etc). How would I need to tweak it?

Comment: perhaps you also need to setup `rc` path, just like the rest of tools?

Comment: @VTT Do you mind elaborating on what an `rc` path is and where I would add its setting in my build script?

Comment: Try running it your `build.bat` via "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019", located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat`

Comment: Neither adding `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` nor
`call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"` fixes the issue. Same error.

Comment: AFAIK `call` will start new process and not affect your local environment. Try adding straight `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"` to your `build.bat`. Or first manually try if it is a solution.

Comment: Adding on to RT2T's comment about running in "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019", I would on top of that try changing the call to just `call "cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"`. That command prompt has the paths set up to include the paths to all the c++ build tools included with the VS installation.