# Unable to resolve : "cl.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: cmake, llvm

I am trying to build llvm source code from ninja.

I am following the http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html
guidelines.

When I try to run command on developer command prompt 
`cmake -G Ninja ../llvm -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra" -DLLVM_BUILD_TESTS=ON`

It is throwing error

```
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27032.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27032.1
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/Desktop/clang-llvm/cmake/cmake-3.15.1-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/Desktop/clang-llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/Desktop/clang-llvm/ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_2dc03 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_2dc03.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
    [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_2dc03.exe
    FAILED: cmTC_2dc03.exe
    cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Desktop\clang-llvm\cmake\cmake-3.15.1-win64-x64\bin\cmake.exe -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_2dc03.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MIB055~1\2017\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2dc03.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_2dc03.exe /implib:cmTC_2dc03.lib /pdb:cmTC_2dc03.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
    RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_2dc03.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_2dc03.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
    The system cannot find the file specified
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Desktop/clang-llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Desktop/clang-llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried to run a program with 
`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe` and there was no error.

Please let me know if there is solution? Thank you in advance:)

Comment: It seems the very similar issue as in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267461/cmake-with-msvc-ninja-gives-compiler-test-program-error) asked 2 hours ago.

Comment: okay. In one of the comment , ```rc``` was mentioned..I can find rc in ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86```.So i should add  this path to the Environment variable

Answer (score 4):

I fell into a similar situation and was able to fix it by **installing another Windows SDK** in "Visual Studio Installer".

I just unselected the currently checked "Windows SDK 10" and selected the latest "Windows 11 SDK" and everything goes fine as before.

See also [Linker Tools Error LNK1104 - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-170).

However, I don't know the reasons behind these. If my memory serves, I just updated Visual Studio via the Visual Studio Installer days before.

Answer (score 1):

Packages might be missing. When I first installed Visual Studio, I didn't install anything for C++ development. If you go to the Visual Studio Installer and then modify, you can install additional packages. I think you might miss some for C++ development and compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps below:

1) Check where rc.exe is located and add its path to environmment variable `PATH`

In my case it was located here

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86`

2) Run developer command prompt in administrator mode.