# CMake error: The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, ninja

I'm compiling an app with CMake but when I do I keep getting this error message.

CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:17 (cmake_policy):
The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
of CMake.

The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32217.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.35.32217.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
The C compiler

```
"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.35.32215/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe"
```

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-td24in

Run Build Command(s):C:/Ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_642ae && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_642ae.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_642ae.exe
FAILED: cmTC_642ae.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_642ae.dir --rc=rc --mt=CMAKE_MT-NOTFOUND --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1435~1.322\bin\Hostx86\x86\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_642ae.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_642ae.exe /implib:cmTC_642ae.lib /pdb:cmTC_642ae.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
RC Pass 1: command "rc /fo CMakeFiles\cmTC_642ae.dir/manifest.res CMakeFiles\cmTC_642ae.dir/manifest.rc" failed (exit code 0) with the following output:
The system cannot find the file specified
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling CMake but even when I do I still get this error message.

Comment: The error is about not finding `rc` executable in your environment. See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57269635/unable-to-resolve-cl-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program) for possible ways of fixing that error.